# Spots on Shady Lady leaves - steps to improve

Tags: trees, leaves, diseases, fungus

I recently had a Shady Lady tree, (Bucida buceras) the black olive tree), installed in my yard. This was the biggest and best-looking tree at the nursery but I am now realizing why it might have been off on its own to the side. Maybe since it was bigger it had more stress when it was balled and burlapped and that led to the disease shown below.

I want to do everything I can to get this tree as healthy as possible. I am trying to diagnose the spots on the leaves. From my research, it is probably some type of fungus. I am also wondering what I can do to help the tree fight it off and get to full strength.

Thanks for any information and ideas!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess the tree is planted somewhere warm all year?  Where is it?

Comment: the nursery brought it from Miami up north a bit to the Tampa bay area. That's where it's planted now

Comment: The new leaves show no signs of fungus, so what you're looking at may (I stress, "may") be a fungal issue that occurred in and was treated at the nursery.